# Migrating Jasper Reports to SpagoBI Server

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, spagobi

I have two servers running:

The first one is a Jasper Server with multiple working reports.

The second one is a freshly installed SpagoBI Server.
Now the Jasper Server should not longer be used and the reports need to be migrated on the SpagoBI Server.

Is there a way to transfer/convert the reports easily?

My prefered (but naive) solution would be a simple ex- and import but unfortunately I haven't found such an option yet.
Another way that comes to my mind, could be using the clients (iReports/SpagoBI Studio).

With iReports I can access the repository of the Jasper Server but unfortunately I can't connect it to the SpagoBI Server.

Comment: you cannot migrate reports from jasper server to SpagoServer.
In SpagoServer you have to create datasets if you want to query to run from dataset OR simply create a document on Spago server without using dataset and upload document and create parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Abhishekkumar. The method of creating an empty document and uploading the .jrxml, I already read about on another page. The probleme here ist that some of these reports have multiple sub reports.
Displaying these results in multiple exceptions:

Comment: `24 Aug 2015 14:09:22,953 ERROR it.eng.spagobi.utilities.engines.AbstractEngineStartServlet.handleException:64 - Service execution failed
...
Caused by: it.eng.spagobi.engines.jasperreport.JasperReportEngineRuntimeException: Impossible to run report
...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : repo:/icinga/styles/IcingaStyleBase.jrtx`
Reports without sub reports are at least displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: When you create subreports on spago server don't include dataset in them just add the query in report.Otherwise it will not get compiled and results in the above error.